# Can I get at the DbContext created by LinqPad?

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

I am trying to test my IRepository interface via linqpad.  To make one I have a constructor that looks like this:

```
IRepository dataAccess = new GenericRepository(dbContext);
```

This works fine in my own code, but I don't know how to get at the dbContext in linqpad.  (I would rather not create my own if I don't have to.

All my code uses IRepository (so that I can unit test).  I can't test it in LinqPad unless I can make a GenericRepository using the dbContext.

**Any idea how I can get at the DbContext that LinqPad creates?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just needed to set the connection to my EF Connection.  After that I could use the `this` keyword and it worked.